# Do strings make a copy of the data in it's constructor

Tags: c++, string, unique-ptr

In the following function (modified from another Stackoverflow post), I'm trying to use a `unique_ptr` so the memory allocated by the `new` gets freed later.

Is it safe to do `std::wstring(res.get())` here? That is, will `res` be copied when the string constructor is called, so that if the memory allocated by `new` is freed, the returned value doesn't become garbage?

```
std::wstring narrow_to_wide_str(const std::string& input) {
    size_t size = input.size() + 1;
    size_t out_size;
    std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> res{ new wchar_t[size] };
    mbstowcs_s(&out_size, res.get(), size, input.c_str(), size - 1);
    return std::wstring(res.get());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it safe to do `std::wstring(res.get())` here?

**Yes.**

From [**std::basic_string::basic_string**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

> basic_string( const CharT* s,
>                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
>       (5)
>
> 5) Constructs the string with the contents **initialized with a copy of the null-terminated character string pointed to by s**. The length of the string is determined by the first null character. The behavior is undefined if [s, s + Traits::length(s)) is not a valid range (for example, if s is a null pointer). This constructor is not used for class template argument deduction if the Allocator type that would be deduced does not qualify as an allocator. (since C++17)

(Emphasize mine.)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `std::string_view` does the opposite.

Comment: @JVApen For the specific case of OP, `std::string_view` would be a bad alternative. The local `res` goes out of scope at the end of function, destroying the `wchar_t[]` pointee, and would make the `std::string_view` dangling.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's safe, but you don't need to use a pointer to a `wchar_t[]` here:

```
std::wstring narrow_to_wide_str(const std::string& input) {
    std::wstring res(input.size() + 1, L'\0');
    size_t out_size;
    mbstowcs_s(&out_size, res.data(), res.size(), input.c_str(), input.size());
    res.resize(out_size);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Should the 3rd argument be `res.size() + 1`?

Comment: @simonzack No, `res.size() == input.size() + 1` already so that shouldn't be needed. "_`dstsz` - max number of wide characters that will be written (size of the dst array)_"

Comment: Hmm this version you need to do `res.resize(out_size - 1)` to exclude the terminating null character in the string.

Comment: It's a lot cheaper than to create a new string by reading the `wchar_t*` until it finds a null terminator to create a new string. The `resize` operation typically just decreases the internal size parameter of the string.

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment, I meant `res.resize(out_size - 1)`. With `res.resize(out_size)`, the string will have an extra null character.

Comment: That's odd: "_Return value: zero on success (in which case the number of wide characters **excluding** terminating zero that were, or would be written to dst, is stored in *retval)_"

Comment: On [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mbstowcs-s-mbstowcs-s-l?view=vs-2019) it says `If mbstowcs_s successfully converts the source string, it puts the size in wide characters of the converted string, including the null terminator, into *pReturnValue`.

Comment: @simonzack Ok, I was reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbstowcs so perhaps MSVC doesn't follow the C11 standard - or the info on cppreference is wrong.

Comment: I looked at the pdf for the standard, and looks like MSVC doesn't follow the standard. The standard is the same for both C11 and C18.